# Отметить radio значением из БД

Tags: база-данных, form

Привет.
Подскажите, а можно ли сделать при выводе формы так, чтобы radio buttom был уже отмечен соответсвующим значением из БД.

К примеру, я заполняю профиль пользователя, там есть варианты "Да" или "Нет" в некоторых пунктах. Я все сохранил, значения в БД занеслись, но форма в следующий раз опять показывает неотмеченные кнопки. Вот в `input type="text"` это сделать знаю как, а тут как?

Comment: Как вы связываете данные из базы данных и html-код? Вы же о html говорить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводим форму с radio и в зависимости от инфы в базе меняем атрибут checked.
Например, выбор пола.  
Берем из базы пол (0-м 1-ж) и записываем в переменную:

```
$pol=<инфа_из_базы>
$checked='';
if ($pol==0) $checked=' checked';
?>
<input type="radio" name="p" value="0" <?php echo $checked;?>> М 
<?php
$checked='';
if ($pol==1) $checked=' checked';
?>
<input type="radio" name="p" value="1" <?php echo $checked;?>> Ж 
<?php
?>
```

Comment: Нет, например когда в форме есть input type="text" можно прописать value="Значение из базы взять", а можно ли так сделать для radio, чтобы соответсвующий радио был отмечен?

Comment: @Batyabest, опишите ситуацию целиком, какие инпуты задействованы и как должны влиять друг на друга.

Comment: @Batyabest, обновил пример.

Comment: Спасибо, наверное, то, что нужно. Попробую отпишусь.

Answer (score 2):

Вот кому, может, пригодится:

```
/**
* Возврат чекбоксов 
* @param $id integr
* @param $return integr
* @return string
*/ 
    function returnCheck($id, $return) 
    { 
       return ($id == $return) ? 'checked="checked"' : NULL; 
    }
```